# Inject values into MSI

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

We are developing an enterprise solution using .Net that includes a ASP.NET MVC website and a Windows Forms developer tool that is used by few users at each customer site.

We are creating a MSI install for the developer tool using WIX and the developer tool needs an App.config customized for each customer (mainly a connection string to connect to the central database used by the solution).
The developers then download the installer from the MVC website and install.
I am hoping to making the tool find the central database without any user interaction.

I don’t want to compile a separate MSI installer for each customer as they are getting too many but was hoping that I could inject the value from the website when it is downloaded or do it once when the website is installed by our upgrade/setup tool.

I currently have not found any way of injecting the value, instead as a stopgap solution I was planning to let the user enter the URL of the MVC website which would then serve up the configuration values.
I would rather want to have this automatic.

Can anyone help me find an approach to this problem?

Comment: Either way, doesn't someone need to 'manually' enter the data at some point?

Comment: @AndrewBarber The website and the upgrade tool that installs the website knows the configuration value so I was hoping as a part of the website install it could edit the MSI itself so the end users (developers) would not have to configure the client.

Comment: @TomBlodget I would prefer it to work without having to drop to Command Prompt. Just download from website and double click the installer.

Comment: @TomBlodget Sorry Tom, I did not read that close enough. This probably solves my problem :) Thanks!